# Play 2.4.X: How to Upload a File without Saving It to a Temporary File

Tags: scala, file-upload, playframework, multipartform-data

The following code snippet shows how to save an uploaded file into MongoDB directly:

```
object MyController extends Controller {

  ...

  def saveImage = Action.async(fsBodyParser) { implicit request =>
    val result = for { file <- request.body.files.head.ref
      update <- {
        fsService.update(
          file.id,
          Json.obj("metadata" -> Json.obj("category" -> "image"))
        )
      }
    } yield update

    result.map { _ =>
      Created(success).withHeaders(LOCATION -> s"${localHost.baseUrl}${request.uri}")
    }
  }

  private def fsBodyParser()(
    implicit fsService: FsServiceComponent#FsService
  ): BodyParser[MultipartFormData[Future[MetaFile]]] = {
    import BodyParsers.parse._

    multipartFormData(Multipart.handleFilePart {
      case Multipart.FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
        fsService.iteratee(filename, contentType)
    })
  }
}
```

The code above compiles and works correctly up to Play 2.3.x... while if I try to compile it with Play 2.4.x I always get the following error messages:

```
[error] /home/j3d/Projects/test/app/controllers/MyController.scala:71: not found: value handleFilePart
[error]     multipartFormData(handleFilePart {
[error]                       ^
[error] /home/j3d/Projects/test/app/controllers/MyController:72: not found: value FileInfo
[error]       case FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
[error]            ^
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jan 3, 2015 2:11:47 PM
```

Look at the latest version of [Multipart.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/parsers/Multipart.scala)... `Multipart.handleFilePart` is `private` now, and it looks like there is no other option than `handleFilePartAsTemporaryFile`. Why? Is there a workaround?